# Oracle's dbms_metadata.get_ddl for object_type JOB

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, jobs, ora-06512, dbms-metadata

I'd like to create ddl scripts for most of my database objects. [dbms_metadata.get_ddl](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html) works for most of the object types. For instance the following creates the ddl for a view:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ( 'VIEW', 'SAMPLE_VIEW') from dual
```

On the other hand it's not working for object_type 'JOB'. The following:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'JOB', 'SAMPLE_JOB' ) from dual
```

gives the following error:

```
ORA-31604: invalid NAME parameter "NAME" for object type JOB in function SET_FILTER
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 116
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 4705
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 8582
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2882
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 2748
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 4333
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If I list my jobs using

```
select * from user_objects where object_type='JOB'
```

it shows SAMPLE_JOB (just like it shows SAMPLE_VIEW if filtered for object_type='VIEW').

Why is it working for VIEW (and TABLE, INDEX, TRIGGER, ...) and not for JOB?

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ', 'yourJobNameGoesHere') from dual;
```

PROCOBJ's are procedural objects.

Comment: An additional note - Oracle was supposed to fix this in 11.2 so it works without this magic - haven't checked.

Comment: @dpbradley - they haven't, at least not as of 11.2.0.1.0 (Linux x86-64).

Comment: Is it possible to also see what is job doing, not only schedule?

Answer (score 3):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ',['JOB'|'PROGRAM'|'SCHEDULE'],'OWNER') from dual;
```

The `PROCOBJ` can be JOB, PROGRAM and SCHEDULE.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, get all jobs from the database with their DDL:

```
select owner, job_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ', job_name, owner) as ddl_output from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I tried all above to get DDL in Oracle version 10g, but no success.

Here is what I figure out to get the detail of the job:

```
set pages 200 lines 200
col owner format a20
col job_name format a25
col JOB_ACTION format a75
col COMMENTS format a60  

select owner, job_name, next_run_date, state, enabled from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name like '%AUDIT%'; 
-- get the detail of scheduled jobs.

select OWNER,JOB_NAME, JOB_ACTION, COMMENTS FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where JOB_NAME='PURGE_AUDIT_LOG';
-- get the limited detail from the selected column.
    
select * FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where JOB_NAME='PURGE_AUDIT_LOG';
-- to get the complete detail of a specific job along with code and other details.
```